# HTML5 semantic elements Vs. div tags

Tags: html, css

It has been almost two weeks since I started 
learning about the essential front-end materials.
I noticed that a lot of people use `<div class="something"></div>`
to specify contents. Rarely do I see people using
HTML5 semantic elements. Perhaps, too many div classes.

But if div classes and semantic elements serve a similar purpose,
why do people say it's a bad practice to use div tags? Does semantic elements
truly boost a website's SEO?

I'm fairly new to the front-end development. Any kind of answer would help me grow as a front-end trainee!

Comment: Its easier for things like web crawlers to parse content when you have tags like `<nav>` and `<article>` than something like this `<div class="myNavbar">`. And when your content can be categorized and filtered better, then everybody wins... users get what they want and websites get the traffic they want.

Comment: Also, the HTML5 tags can make for cleaner, more readable code. Getting lost in a sea of `</div></div></div></div>` isn't fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't a correct answer here.  There is cases to use some of the new HTML5 semantic elements such as header, nav, or footer.  But there is cases to just use div's as well.

It really comes down to your style as a dev.  Me personally I like using the header, nav, and footer tags but using div's for most everything else.

To play devil's advocate with that though you could get a really long CSS selector like `.section .row .column .some-item .another-item`.  That is bad.  That would perform really slow.  The way that selector works is it starts from `.another-item` and works its way backwards...

If you used some of the semantic elements it could make a better CSS selector and thus a faster page.

Comment: Do you have any source for the claim on performance? Also I think you are missing some critical points such as machine readability.

Comment: @BramVanroy: Wait, what is machine readability...?

Answer (score 2):

It's best to use semantic tags so machines could better understand the content of a website (SEO, screen-readers, scrappers, 3rd-party scripts, browser addons..)

For a computer it's not very easy to tell which area is the main navigation, which is the header, which is main content area, and so on. it really helps a lot (from a machine point-of-view) of you use tags which describes the meaning of each area of your HTML.

---

#### See these answers here:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/18472/38951
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/2757/38951

Comment: So, as a consequence, there may be some SEO benefit of using HTML 5 because it better allows crawlers to judge which information is relevant and which is not, or e.g. who's the author, the time an article was created,  and so on.

Comment: @BramVanroy - well, you can add microdata for those things also. [read more](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data)